# PDFTron - app.launchURL is not working with PDF Button in chrome

Tags: pdftron

We are showing pdf file in PDFTron webviewer(webviewer 5.2.9 legacy-ui) and PDF contains form fields and button, So on click on button we are extracting value from input and open url with argument. Below is the code snippet of button click.

Note : This works fine in Adobe and Foxit reader.

```
var p1 = this.getField("FirstName").value;
app.launchURL('http://localhost:8080/submit?FirstName='+p1,true);
```

When I click on button it is showing "**webviewer-core.min.js:193 stub: app.launchURL called with: [object Arguments]**" but it is not launching url.

Please see below snap for more details.

[image]

Comment: What framework are you using? What is the "app" object exactly and what is the "launchURL" API (give URL to API reference)?

Comment: Question updated, Please refer for more details and please let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the launch API is not implemented yet, however, you can update the `launchURL` function by yourself by using:

```
Annotations.Forms.EmbeddedJS.update(scope => {
  scope.app.launchURL = function(url) {
     window.open(url);
  };
});
```

You can check more detail here https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/forms/embedded-js/#customization